# Overlap between Objective-C and MATLAB/Octave file extensions

Tags: objective-c, matlab, octave, file-extension

Do Objective-C or MATLAB/Octave have source file extensions besides `.m`? I ask because I'm putting Hello World programs in a single folder and I can't have two `hello.m` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to use `.mm` for Objective-C. `.mm` is used for Objective-C++ source files and it is a superset of Objective-C so it should compile fine.

This is by no mean a clean solution. A much better way would be to reorganize your folder into subfolders as suggested by Ruddy Velthuis, or simply to call your source files `hello-objective-c.m` and `hello-matlab.m`.

Comment: There are many subtle differences between Objective-C and Objective-C++. I would use subfolders or compiler settings to use other extensions than .m for Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I see is to create subdirectories for each of the programs and put your files there. You can tell Obj-C to treat other extensions as Obj-C, but that would not solve the problem for the other programs.

Update

To compile any extension as Objective-C, use `-x objective-c` on the command line or Select Objective-C from "Compile Sources As" in the target build settings. Default is "According To File Type", which means that only .m files are compield as Objective-C.

FWIW, there are many subtle differences between Objective-C++ and Objective-C. I myself would use subfolders to separate the .m files, as I already said above.

Comment: How does one tell Obj-C to treat other extensions at Objc-C?

Comment: Use `-x objective-c` on the command line or "Compile Sources As" in the Targets settings (show all).

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB cannot find files unless they have the `.m` extension (very important!)

Now I know very little about Objective-C, I presume it's a superset of C (just like C++ is). If so, and similar to C/C++, you should be able to pass any file name as input to the compiler:

```
g++ -c myfile.m.txt
```

Comment: Even if the compiler can handle a single abnormal ObjC file extension, the various header files might not work well with them.

Comment: It's a superset of C, unlike C++, which is not a superset of C.

Comment: @mcandre: I guess as other have suggested, the best thing to do is to separate the files in different folders